# Bat command error cannot find specified file

Tags: batch

I have written this simple batch to truncate a table but when I try to run it on this particular server (Windows 2008) it comes back with an error. The system cannot find the file specified.

The same script works fine and others clients servers but this one.

```
cd D:\DRS\MYSQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin
mysql --user=root --password=XM8raC3atDR$ --database=connectorckh  <H:\TruncateOptRequest\Query1.sql
pause

query1.sql file : truncate table connectorckh.tblxmb_optitimewebxmlrequests
```

Comment: Can you try putting quotations around that path like this: cd "D:\DRS\MYSQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin mysql --user=root --password=XM8raC3atDR$ --database=connectorckh"

Comment: Also take out the last line and just have the first line then run the bat file from command prompt and see that it gets you to the path, if so you know the first line works and the second line is causing the problem.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and it is indeed the second line that is causing the issue, it access MySQL fine but the truncate command is in a separate file called "Query.sql" and it doesn't seem to find it.

Comment: It was the Query file name. it had hidden extension of txt.

Comment: ahh that is a pain, when you save files in notepad to another extension always quotation then "example.bat" that stops them becoming example.bat.txt